# Merge entries from the same table, alternating empty columns

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have a table on SQL Server, with the following structure:

```
ID           int identity not null,
Name_English nvarchar(max),
Name_Spanish nvarchar(max),
```

Due to migrations, the current data on the table looks something like this:

```
ID  Name_English    Name_Spanish
1   'Architecture'  null
2   null            'Arquitectura'
3   'Music'         null
4   'Sculpture'     null
5   null            'Música'
6   null            'Escultura'
```

I would like to merge them, so that they look this way:

```
ID  Name_English    Name_Spanish
1   'Architecture'  'Arquitectura'
3   'Music'         'Música'
4   'Sculpture'     'Escultura'
```

The exact ID is not important, but it is used for the order (that's why Architecture shouldn't get merged with Música). Also, they're not guaranteed to be alternating one by one. The original data was updated in blocks.

I was thinking of using `MERGE` and sorting by `ROW_NUMBER()`, but I don't quite know how to create the query using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a revised query based on the updated sample data.  As proposed, this does leverage `ROW_NUMBER()`.

We start with the full table, inner joining to all the English words sorted, then outer join to all the Spanish words sorted in the proper order.  Note that we join from the main `YourTable` to the `EnglishSorted` based on the original ID, then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` to join up the `EnglishSorted` and `SpanishSorted` sets.  This lets us ultimately update all the English rows to get the corresponding Spanish row's `Name_Spanish` data.

Finally, we run the `DELETE` statement to wipe out all the original Spanish rows, as they are now redundant.

```
UPDATE
  YourTable
SET
  Name_Spanish = SpanishSorted.Name_Spanish
FROM
  YourTable
  INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [YourTable].[ID] ASC) AS [TempID],
     YourTable.[ID], 
     YourTable.Name_English
   FROM
     YourTable
   WHERE
     YourTable.Name_English IS NOT NULL
  ) EnglishSorted ON YourTable.[ID] = EnglishSorted.[ID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
  SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [YourTable].[ID] ASC) AS [TempID],
     YourTable.[ID], 
     YourTable.Name_Spanish
   FROM
     YourTable
   WHERE
     YourTable.Name_Spanish IS NOT NULL
  ) SpanishSorted ON EnglishSorted.[TempID] = SpanishSorted.[TempID]
;

DELETE YourTable WHERE YourTable.Name_English IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM YourTable;
```

This is available as a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7328/3) to play with.

---

The following is the original answer, which just leverages the "every other" structure of the original question sample date.  I'm leaving it here so the comments below make sense.

I don't think you need `MERGE` or to utilize `ROW_NUMBER()` here.  Given your sample data...

```
UPDATE 
    EnglishOnly
SET
    EnglishOnly.Name_Spanish = SpanishOnly.Name_Spanish
FROM
    YourTable EnglishOnly
    LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable SpanishOnly ON EnglishOnly.[ID] + 1 = SpanishOnly.[ID]
WHERE
    EnglishOnly.Name_English IS NOT NULL
```

To remove the redundant rows...

```
DELETE Your_Table WHERE YourTable.Name_English IS NULL;
```

Comment: This seems to work, but the way the data was entered, it's not guaranteed for the English entries to be odd-numbered and the Spanish be even-numbered. I will update the question.

Comment: Damn, based on your initial sample data I thought we were guaranteed every other.  With the revised example, are we guaranteed that the next row after a row containing a non-null value for `Name_English` that contains a null value for `Name_English` will contain the corresponding `Name_Spanish`? Even then, you'd have to backtrack to catch English words you skipped when seeking the Spanish row, and then avoid re-using the previously passed (then backtracked in front of again) Spanish definition (to avoid 'Music' and 'Sculpture' both getting 'Música' in your revised sample data).

Comment: Yes, having a null value in English is guaranteed to have a value in Spanish and viceversa.

Comment: I was thinking of using `ROW_NUMBER` to generate a fake ID, so that I could `JOIN` them. Since the original ID reflects the sorting order, that would pair the items correctly.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Is this more now in line with something that will work with your data?